# Need Help - Gitian Setup for Linux

Tags: gitian

I'm having hard time using Gitian... Yes there are instructions there but its not full. It's only setup.. but it really difficult to learn and use. I have been reading about other ways of using Gitian... Im trying to compile QT for Windows and Linux and also a MAc...

So my question is do I need to have Debian installed to use Gitian? I'm using Linux Mint (Ubuntu 16.04) and I did manage to install but Im running into errors and I dont understand what is it that im doing wrong?

Do you have any really good guiding instruction for this? I've tried searching and just time consuming. Any other better way of using Gitian?

Thanks.

---

Ok so this is the error... I have the folder inside the gitian and even in the input folder. (the coin source file)

I tried different ways of doing.. I will post more.

[image: This is the error]

Comment: The only good gitian guide I know of is the one I assume you already found. Could you please post the errors you are getting so we can try and help